# How to reduce $\frac{1}{3}(4^{k+1} -1 + 3\cdot4^{ k+1})$ to $\frac{1}{3}(4\cdot4^{k+1}-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you reduce $\frac{1}{3}(4^{k+1} -1 + 3\cdot4^{
k+1})$ to $\frac{1}{3}(4\cdot4^{k+1}-1)$?

These are the two steps in the back of my book, but can someone tell me the intermediate steps to get from one to the other? A little background, this is part of a Proof by Mathematical Induction problem and the idea is to have it match $\frac{1}{3}(4^{k+2} -1 )$ at the end.

Comment: By noting that $3\cdot K + K = 4 \cdot K$.  So $3\cdot 4^{k+1} + 4^{k+1} = 4\cdot 4^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $4^{k+1} = GOMBAHFOOZAH$

Then this becomes $\frac{1}{3}(4^{k+1} -1 + 3\cdot4^{
k+1})=$

$\frac{1}{3}(GOMBAHFOOZAH -1 + 3\cdot GOMBAHFOOZAH)=$

$\frac 13(4\cdot GOMBAHFOOZAH - 1) =$

$\frac 13(4\cdot 4^{k+1} - 1)$ (and we can go further)

$= \frac 13 (4^{(k+1)+1} - 1)=$

$\frac 13 (4^{k+2} - 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{3}(4^{k+1} -1 + 3\cdot4^{
k+1})=\frac{1}{3}(4^{k+1} + 3\cdot4^{
k+1}-1)=\frac{1}{3}(4^{k+1} (1+ 3)-1)=\frac{1}{3}(4^{k+1}\cdot4-1)$$